# Как в стандартное меню ввода Edit Memo вставить свой пункт меню

Tags: delphi, winapi

Как в стандартное меню ввода Edit Memo вставить свой пункт меню

[image: png]

Comment: Поскольку это меню создаётся самой windows, то нет стандартного способа изменить его. Возможно, через какой-то хак и можно туда что-то впихнуть, но не факт...